# How to show busy activity in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I would like to somehow give the user a busy status while my script is processing. I can't seem to get it to work.  Things only happen after the search is complete.  It's a web app script.

I have a specific search (limits searching to sub folders only with GDrive) and while it is processing, I'd like to give feed back it is.  It takes quite some time so there may be speed-up I can do as well, but non the less, I'd like to have a busy ticker, prompt, change the button label - anything. This script is in a GSite page on our apps domain.

I define the the entry and button like this:

```
// set text boxes for second column
grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setId("search")
     .setName("search").setWidth(500));

// create button and handler
grid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createButton("Search")
     .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("findFiles").addCallbackElement(grid))
     .setId('button'));
```

...

```
var msg = app.createLabel().setId('msg');
app.add(msg);
```

The UI looks like this:
  [image: UI for Search]

I then process as such:

```
//
//  [ initiate the find process ]
//
function findFiles(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var msg = app.getElementById('msg');

//----> doesn't appear until search is complete?!
  showMsg("...searching, please wait..."); 

  // 
  //  NOTE: This is hardcoded to look in folders that 
  //        have "! Portal !" in their name ONLY
  //
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('title contains "! Portal !"');
  while (folders.hasNext()) { 
    var folder = folders.next();
    showItems(folder, e.parameter.search);
  }

  if(!g_found) {
    msg.setText("Sorry, nothing found. Refresh this page to try again");
  } else {  
    msg.setText("Search is complete. Click file names to open documents.");
  }

  return app;
}

function showMsg(text) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   app.getElementById('msg').setText(text);
   return app;
}

//
//  [ nested search ]
//
function showItems(folder, search) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var files = folder.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + search + '"');
  while(files.hasNext()) {

    g_found = true;
    var file = files.next();

    var link = app.createAnchor(file.getName(), file.getUrl());  // ...URL of file found
    app.add(link);

    var lf = app.createHTML('');         // ...add a break between URLs found
    app.add(lf);

  }  

  var subFldrs = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFldrs.hasNext()) { 
    var fldr = subFldrs.next();
    showItems(fldr, search);              // ...recursive searching
  }

  return app;
}
```

I've tried things like getting the button ID and changing it's text etc.  Nothing works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution...

I needed a ***client handler*** instead.

So the code for defining the button looks like this...

```
  var msg = app.createLabel().setId('msg');
```

...

```
  // create button and handler
  grid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createButton('Search')
                 .setId('button')
                 .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('findFiles').addCallbackElement(grid))
                 .addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                                  .forEventSource().setText('...searching...')
                                  .forEventSource().setEnabled(false)
                                  .forTargets(msg).setText('..processing, please wait...') ) );
```

...

```
  app.add(grid);
  app.add(msg);
```

This works to show the button change and processing msg immediately!
My findFiles() function now looks like this...

```
function findFiles(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var msg = app.getElementById('msg');

  // 
  //  NOTE: This is hardcoded to look in folders that 
  //        have "! Portal !" in their name ONLY
  //
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('title contains "! Portal !"');
  while (folders.hasNext()) { 
    showItems(folders.next(), e.parameter.search);
  }

  if(!g_found) {
    msg.setText("Sorry, nothing found. Refresh this page to try again");
  } else {  
    msg.setText("Search is complete. Click file names to open documents.");
  }

  // ...restore button
  app.getElementById('button').setText('Search').setEnabled(true);

  return app;
}
```

:v)

Comment: I won't mark this as answered for a bit to see if anyone else has a better/other idea.

Comment: I might add that this isn't ideal.  The reason being, if I want to handle Enter being pressed in the textbox, I'm back to nothing updating again.  It's gotta be something to do with the server call not returning?!

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution**

This solution works for either clicking the search button or a KeyDown event being [Enter].
The user receives processing indicators either way.

I'll give the entire script below as it has several changes overall:

```
// Google Info Portal Search
//
// This script is embedded in a GSite page via: Insert -> Apps Script Gadget.
// It is used to search ONLY the folders starting with "! Portal "
//

// 
//  [ globals ]
//
var g_Fnd = 0;


//
//    [ initial 'main' function for web app ]
//
function doGet() {

  // create app and grid
  var app  = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  var grid = app.createGrid(3,3).setId('grid');    

  // set label for search
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel("Enter your search text and click the [Search] button: ")
                 .setStyleAttribute('fontWeight', 'bold'));

  // set text boxes for second column
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setId('search')
                 .setName("search").setWidth(500)
                 .addKeyPressHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkKeyDown').addCallbackElement(grid))
                 .addKeyPressHandler(app.createServerHandler('showProcessing').addCallbackElement(grid)) );

  // create button and handler
  grid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createButton('Search')
                 .setId('button')
                 .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('showProcessing').addCallbackElement(grid))
                 .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('findFiles'     ).addCallbackElement(grid)) );

  // processing / error messages 
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createLabel().setId('msg'));

  // add widgets to application and show the app
  app.add(grid);

  return app;
}


//
//  [ check for the Enter key ]
//
function checkKeyDown(event) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  if(event.parameter.keyCode == 13) {
    findFiles(event);
  } 

  return app;
}


//
//  [ show user processing activity ]
//
function showProcessing(event) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  if((event.parameter.search > '') &&
     ((event.parameter.keyCode == 13) || (event.parameter.eventType == 'click')) ) {
    app.getElementById('button').setText(' searching ').setEnabled(false);
    app.getElementById('msg').setText('...processing - please wait...');
  }

  return app;
}


//
//  [ initiate the find process ]
//
function findFiles(event) {

  var app  = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var msg  = app.getElementById('msg');
  var srch = event.parameter.search;

  // NOTE: Results are cummulative, until the page is refreshed.

  g_Fnd = 0;

  if(srch <= '') {
    msg.setText('You haven\'t entered anything to look for? Please enter search text.');    
    app.getElementById('button').setText('Search').setEnabled(true);

    return app;
  }

  // 
  //  NOTE: The next line is hardcoded to look in Portal folders ONLY
  //
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('title contains "! Portal "');
  while (folders.hasNext()) { 
    showItems(folders.next(), srch);
  }

  if(g_Fnd) {
    msg.setText('Search is complete. Click file links to open documents.');    
  } else {  
    msg.setText('Sorry, nothing found. Refresh this page to try again');
  }

  // ...restore button for next search
  app.getElementById('button').setText('Search').setEnabled(true);

  return app;
}


//
//  [ nested search ]
//
function showItems(folder, search) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var files = folder.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + search + '"');
  var file;

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();  
    app.add(app.createAnchor(file.getName()+'<br>', true, file.getUrl()));
    g_Fnd++;
  }  

  var subFldrs = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFldrs.hasNext()) { 
    showItems(subFldrs.next(), search);              // ...recursive searching 
  }

  return app;
}
```

This code isn't terribly robust ;-P (no try/catch etc), but it does the job for now.
Hopefully it's useful to other who search here :-)